# Why would HR set up a 15 minute video call following final interview rounds? See below for details

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I had final rounds of interviews 2 days ago (this past Wednesday). The Senior HR person I interviewed with said that they are considering a few other candidates as well in the running. When I asked for when they are trying to make a final decision by, they said by the end of the following week.

I sent a thank you note to the interviewers one day after the interview (they did not respond to the thank you note)....but I received an email from a junior HR associate two days after the final interview (ie today, Friday) and they said they would like to set up a quick 15 minute video call for me with the same Senior HR person I interviewed with...on Monday, after the weekend is over. Why would they set up this video call?  After setting up the call, they said have a great weekend.

Usually, in the past after final rounds of interviews one of the following things has happened to me, either:

1)have received a phone call from HR with verbal offer within 2-3 days

2)have received a rejection email a week or two after if I was not selected (sometimes saying another candidate was selected).

3)never heard back from them ie ghosted.

What would the 15 minute video call be for? Could it be a verbal offer? Could it be to tell me I have to interview with additional people? Could it be for requesting references, any other information? Could it be a rejection/feedback because I was a runner up and to tell me if any other positions open up in the future, they would inform me? Could it be to tell me they are still interviewing the other candidates, its taking a bit longer and will have a decision for me soon?

Any feedback would be appreciated or if anyone has been through this. Thanks!

Comment: We can't tell you. While an offer, or a negotiation over the details of an offer, seem the most likely, in that the other options you've listed probably wouldn't take 15 minutes, none of them are implausible.

Comment: I edited your question title - 15 minute video call is very different from 15 video call !

Answer (score 3):

Thoughts

- Interviewer has 6 more questions to ask you, but ran out of time and cut your interview short to keep on the schedule.
- In talking to other staff perhaps the department where you were going to work, something came up.  They will have the vid call and bring in the other party into it.
- They are trying to rattle you and seeing what you are like after a weekend of anxiety.
- If they are making an an offer verbally instead of in writing, watch for railroading.  Have a good idea ahead of time what you will accept and what you won't.  Watch for gotchas on the perks.  Do NOT accept a verbal offer.  A verbal offer isn't worth the paper it isn't printed on.

Answer (score 3):

> What would the 15 minute video call be for?

We don't know. Could be a large variety of things, but it's typically a good sign

> Could it be a verbal offer? Could it be to tell me I have to interview with additional people? Could it be for requesting references, any other information?

Yes.

> Could it be a rejection/feedback because I was a runner up and to tell me if any other positions open up in the future, they would inform me?

Yes. That would mean that you actually did well in the interview and they want to minimize your frustration and try to keep you interested in future opportunities

> Could it be to tell me they are still interviewing the other candidates, its taking a bit longer and will have a decision for me soon?

Yes.

Most likely: they are getting ready to make an offer and want to work out details and negotiations up front. Creating a written offer can be a lot of work (depending on the approval process) so personally I (as a hiring manager) wouldn't do it until we have worked verbally through all details and I'm reasonably sure that it will be accepted.

It may also be to "take your temperature": before starting the formal offer work, they may want to check what your real level of interest is, if you have competing offers happening and/or if there are specific concerns or potential showstoppers on your side that they need to address first or get covered in the offer.

Could also be a follow up on a concern: compensation, commute, time to start, a certain behavior, a specific skill, etc. That's less likely as 15  minutes is generally short of that type of thing.